# Identify eventlogs in a vector before and after a certain date in r

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I have the following data set which i would like to group and summarize for each sequence. Each sequence should be split into all the events, which occured in the first 7 days after the first date and combine the later events into a seperate group. Basically my biggest challenge is to **find the first date in the sequence, add 7 days and mark all the dates in this sequence which fall into this category**.

```
structure(list(`Sequence ID` = c("1_0_0", "1_0_0", "1_0_0", "1_0_0", 
"1_0_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_2_0", 
"1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_2"), Date = c("02.12.2015 20:16", 
"03.12.2015 20:17", "02.12.2015 20:44", "03.12.2015 09:32", "03.12.2015 09:33", 
"07.12.2015 08:18", "08.12.2015 19:40", "08.12.2015 19:43", "22.12.2015 18:22", 
"22.12.2015 18:23", "23.12.2015 14:18", "05.01.2016 11:35", "05.01.2016 13:21", 
"05.01.2016 13:22", "05.01.2016 13:22", "04.08.2016 08:25"), 
    StimuliA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), StimuliB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Response = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("Sequence ID", "Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", 
"Response"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(`Sequence ID` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), StimuliA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), StimuliB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Response = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), X6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_skip", 
"collector")), X7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_skip", 
"collector")), X8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_skip", 
"collector")), X9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_skip", 
"collector")), X10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_skip", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Sequence ID", "Date", "StimuliA", 
"StimuliB", "Response", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

This could be a possible output, where with Group the 0 summarized all the values in the first 7 days and 1 the values which occured later.

```
Sequence ID Group   Date           StimuliA StimuliB    Response
1_0_0         0   02.12.2015 20:16    0         0           5
1_0_0         1   09.12.2015 20:16    0         0           0
1_1_0         0   07.12.2015 08:18    1         0           2
1_1_0         1   14.12.2015 08:18    0         0           2
1_2_0         0   23.12.2015 14:18    1         0           0
1_2_0         1   30.12.2015 14:18    0         0           0
1_2_1         0   05.01.2016 11:35    0         1           3
1_2_1         1   12.01.2016 11:35    0         0           0
1_2_2         0   04.08.2016 08:25    0         1           0
1_2_2         1   11.08.2016 08:25    0         0           0
```

I would try to achieve this with the following code, but need some inputs how to identify the values before and after 7 days.

```
#change the date into posixct format
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(master$Date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))

#arrange the dataframe according to User and Date
df <-  arrange(df, Sequence ID,Date)

#identify the values before and after 7 days

#aggregate all the eventlog rows according to the stimuli IDs
df <- aggregate(. ~ Sequence ID + Group, data=df, sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `data.table` code returns aggregated values which are grouped by sequence and the period of the first seven days within each sequence (or beyond) as requested:

```
library(data.table)
# copy and coerce to data.table
data.table(DF)[
  # make syntactically valid column names
  , setnames(.SD, make.names(names(.SD)))][
    # transform character date-time to date
    , Date := as.Date(lubridate::dmy_hm(Date))][
      # create Group variable for the first 7 days and beyond within each sequence
      , Initial.Period := Date %between% (min(Date) + c(0L, 6L)), by = Sequence.ID][
        # aggregate by sequence and date range
        , .(Min.Date = min(Date), Response = sum(Response)), by = .(Sequence.ID, Initial.Period)]
```

> ```
>    Sequence.ID Initial.Period   Min.Date Response
> 1:       1_0_0           TRUE 2015-12-02        5
> 2:       1_1_0           TRUE 2015-12-07        2
> 3:       1_1_0          FALSE 2015-12-22        2
> 4:       1_2_0           TRUE 2015-12-23        0
> 5:       1_2_1           TRUE 2016-01-05        3
> 6:       1_2_2           TRUE 2016-08-04        0
> ```

Note that the result differs from the *possible output* shown in the question due to ambiguities or to inconsistencies in the provided sample data:

- The sample data contain date-times but the OP is using the terms *date* and *days* throughout in his specification. Therefore, the code is using `Date` rather than `POSIXct`.
- I've deliberately choosen to use `Initial.Period` as a more speaking column name to indicate the first 7 days and to avoid the generic and ambiguous name `Group`.
- The columns `StimuliA` and `StimuliB` have been omitted from the aggregation because they aren't consistent with the sequences and the OP hasn't specified how to handle this case.
- `Min.Date` refers to the minimum date *in the data* for each sequence and period, not to the calculated beginn of the periods.
- The result shows only aggregated values where data is available in the data set. The *possible output* has more rows because it includes all possible combinations of sequences and periods where missing values have been filled up with zeros.